# iPad orientation issue. When does the app begin to know about its orientation?

Tags: ios

I am implementing an application which is locked to landscape only, containing a `UIScrollView` (the super view to add sub-views) and a `UIPageControl`.

When I trying to add a sub-view in `viewDidLoad`, calculating its frame by referencing its super view's frame, it is always portrait. 
But the sub-view added later (say in the `scrollViewDidScroll`, when user swipes to next page) is landscape.

I set a break point and found that the super view's size is 768*969 in viewDidLoad and 1024 * 713 later.

I suspect it is because the app doesn't know about the orientation at all when `viewDidLoad` thus everything is default to portrait layout. Am I right?

If so, when will the app know about the orientation for the first time?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set Initial Interface Orientation to **Landscape (right home button)** in plist?

Comment: @iApple Of course. And so does the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. It only doesn't work at the start.

Comment: Check in Interface Builde, in your MainWidow.xib, Orientation should be Landscape. Is it?

Comment: @iApple Yes. The app is in landscape. The only thing wrong is that the frame's value seems to be portrait in viewDidLoad. But after that, everything is right.

Comment: Have you set shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method which should be return yes only if the rotation is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found was to reparent the scroll view under an intermediate view

```
 VC
  view
   view (intermediate view)
    scrollview
```

Then the frame of the scroll view was correct in viewdidload (previously without the intermediate view, the frame was in portrait right up until viewdidappear!)